# Comparing two data frames and creating new data frame based on some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame and I need to extract some data based on other data frame. I tried to do it but in some point I couldn't go further. I'm working on pandas.

For example, main data frame is like that:
df1

| fruit |
| --- |
| apple |
| banana |
| grapes |
| blueberry |
| cherry |

And I have another data frame which is like that:
df2

| subdata |
| --- |
| nan |
| pple |
| che |
| lsls |
| lueberry |
| cherry |
| app |

Desired output:

| newdata |
| --- |
| nan |
| pple |
| che |
| lueberry |
| cherry |
| app |

so here, I want to extract the data, if df2 is in df1. For example, in df2 first row I have nan and this is in ba*nan*a, or it also can match. Like in df2 last row I have cherry and it also match with df1 cherry. "lsls" in df2 4th row is not matching with anything in df1 and it wont be extracted. So I want to extract all matching or submatching with df1 and extract those data from df2. I tried to some codes but couldnt do properly. If you help me, I'll be pleased. Thank you.

Comment: just to be clear, so "nan" here is a string value not a missing value?

Comment: not missing value, i think im explaining in questions. It's in banana and it should be extracted also

Comment: i edited question and put the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `apply` for simplicity

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(['apple','banana','grapes','blueberry','cherry'], columns=['fruit'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['nan','pple','che','lsls','lueberry','cherry'], columns=['subdata'])


df3 = df2[df2['subdata'].apply(lambda x: df1['fruit'].str.contains(x).any())]

df3

#   subdata
# 0 nan
# 1 pple
# 2 che
# 4 lueberry
# 5 cherry
```

Comment: thank you, but unfourtanetely, this is not the output that i need. I edited question and put the desired output.

Comment: check the answer @melike8